# How to add empty rows when id is zero using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am adding empty rows to table passing id which is retrieving from database which is working but when i tried to add empty rows when id is zero then

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of null

I dnt understand the issue where it is arising my add function in controller is

```
  $scope.addMachineItems = function (id) {
    ServiceFactory.InvokeWithParameters(baseurl + 'Api/AdminApi/AddRow?machineID=' + id).success(function (success) {
        $scope.machine.machineItemList.push(success);
    }).error(function (error) {
        alert(error);
    })
}
```

In my view i used click like this

```
 <td ng-click="addMachineItems(machine.machine_ID)">
        <a >Add+ </a>
    </td>
```

ng-repeat="machine in  machine.machineItemList"

API Controller code

```
   public MachineTypeItems AddRow(int machineID)
    {
        MachineTypeItems item = new MachineTypeItems();
        item.Isactive = 1;
        item.Machine_ID = machineID;
        return item;
    }
```

can anyone one explain why type error issue is coming and why can't i add empty rows while passing id = 0.
I hope I gave an clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Some source code is missing here.

The problem is not about type error, the problem is that $scope.listinfo is not instantiated when id=0.

Comment: Where is instantation of listinfo ?

Comment: sorry my mistake changed now even i add the ng-repeat